# Adding password protection to a particular url

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have my spring security configuration file like,

```
package com.wi;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import com.wi.HttpAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.wi.filter.AuthenticationFilter;
import com.wi.HttpLogoutSuccessHandler;
import com.wi.LogOutHandler;

/**
 * Web security configuration class
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order( SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER )
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

@Autowired
private HttpAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

@Autowired
private HttpLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

@Autowired
private MessageBundleResource messageBundle;

@Autowired
private LogOutHandler logoutHandler;

@Override
protected void configure( final HttpSecurity http ) throws DataException
{
    try
    {
        http.csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and().headers()
                .cacheControl().and()
                .addHeaderWriter(
                        new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter.XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN))
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                // Allow anonymous resource requests
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().antMatchers("/pages/**").permitAll()
                // Allow anonymous logins
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()

                // Allow test rest
                .antMatchers("/rest-test/**").permitAll()

                // Allow invite admin
                .antMatchers("/rest/user/inviteAdmin").permitAll()

                // Allow activate user
                .antMatchers("/rest/user/activateUser").permitAll()
                // Allow activate admin
                .antMatchers("/rest/user/activateAdmin").permitAll()

                // Allow check domain availability
                .antMatchers("/rest/user/checkDomainAvailability").permitAll()

                // Allow check company and email active
                .antMatchers("/rest/company/checkEmailAndCompanyIsActive").permitAll()

                // Allow check domain by email
                .antMatchers("/rest/user/getDomainByEmail").permitAll()

                // Allow reset password
                .antMatchers("/rest/user/resetPassword").permitAll()

                // Allow to get messages
                .antMatchers("/rest/kat/getMessages").permitAll()
                // upload
                .antMatchers("/rest/file/upload").permitAll()

                // Allow get user details
                .antMatchers("/rest/user/getUserDetails").permitAll()

                // Allow to get password pattern
                .antMatchers("/rest/config/getPasswordPattern").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/rest/task/getCategories").permitAll()

                // Allow to get config messages
                .antMatchers("/rest/config/getTooltip").permitAll()
                // Allow to get webhook
                .antMatchers("/rest/integration/jiraWebHook").permitAll()
                // Allow to get global navigation
                .antMatchers("/rest/config/getGlobalNavigation").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/rest/task/updateTaskDetail").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/rest/task/updateTask").permitAll().antMatchers("/error/**").permitAll()
                // All other request need to be authenticated
                .antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and()
                .logout().addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler).invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler).logoutUrl("/rest/session/logout").and()

                // Custom Token based authentication based on the header
                // previously given to the client
                .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()),
                        BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED).sessionFixation()
                .changeSessionId();

    }
    catch( final Exception e )
    {
        logger.error("Error", e);
        throw new DataException(StringConstants.EXCEPTION,
                messageBundle.getMessage("kat.error.something.went.wrong"), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}

/**
 *
 * @param auth
 */
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal( final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth )
{
    auth.authenticationProvider(domainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider());

}

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider domainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationProvider()
{
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthProvider();
}

}
```

How to make a user prompted for user id and password when he hits the url http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html. The URL's which has a call `permitAll()` will be directly accessed by all. But, when a user hits http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html, I want spring to ask him for user id and password. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of configurations there. basically, every ant matcher *that is not ignored or not permitted to all* will be protected under security, if you applied httpBasic or formLogin security.

For example from spring documentations:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()                                                                1
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()                  2
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      3
            .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")            4
            .anyRequest().authenticated()                                                   5
            .and()
        // ...
        .formLogin();
}
```

any user can access a request if the URL starts with "/resources/", equals "/signup", or equals "/about"

**any other path will trigger formLogin authentication**

Comment: The thing is, I don't want **any other path** to be triggered with formLogin authentication, I want only a single URL to be triggered with form login auth.